# Foxit Reader temporarily freezes reading fonts, how to reduce?

Tags: windows, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

When using Foxit Reader to read pdfs I noticed, that there are certain lags from time to time, where the the reader freezes for some seconds and then continues working later on.

I used the Windows Resource Monitor to track what the application is actually reading and as it turns out, it's the font directory C:\Windows\Fonts and the respective font files.

I should mention, I'm using an ordinary HDD drive for my Windows installation.

Now that I know the problem source, how can I reduce the freezes? Does someone experience similar problems?